# Trigger before insert fire error if there has no data on fetching table.

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `staff_auto_salary` BEFORE INSERT ON `staff_attendance`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
IF NEW.att_present LIKE  'P'
THEN 
SET NEW.wages = (SELECT staff_emp_salary FROM staff_salary WHERE staff_emp_id = NEW.att_staff_id ) / (SELECT DAY( LAST_DAY( NOW( ) ) ) );
ELSEIF NEW.att_present LIKE  'HALF' THEN SET NEW.wages = ( SELECT staff_emp_salary FROM staff_salary WHERE staff_emp_id = NEW.att_staff_id ) / ( SELECT DAY( LAST_DAY( NOW( ) ) ) ) /2;
END IF ;
END
```

Above is my trigger code this trigger added wages as per employee salary which are in staff_emp_salary table. Trigger will fire when insert on staff_attendance table and fetch salary from staff_salary if salary is not in table then it will fire error, so i want if there is no salary for employee in staff_emp_salary table then insert 0.

Comment: Try [IFNULL()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

Comment: With [IFNULL()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull): `SET ... := IFNULL((SELECT ...) / (SELECT ...), 0);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond solution as below.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `staff_auto_salary`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `staff_auto_salary` BEFORE INSERT ON `staff_attendance`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
IF NEW.att_present LIKE  'P'
THEN 
SET NEW.wages = (SELECT IF(count(`staff_emp_salary`)!=0,`staff_emp_salary`,'0') as `staff_emp_salary` FROM staff_salary WHERE staff_emp_id = NEW.att_staff_id ) / (SELECT DAY( LAST_DAY( NOW( ) ) ) );
ELSEIF NEW.att_present LIKE  'HALF' THEN SET NEW.wages = ( SELECT IF(count(`staff_emp_salary`)!=0,`staff_emp_salary`,'0') as `staff_emp_salary` FROM staff_salary WHERE staff_emp_id = NEW.att_staff_id ) / ( SELECT DAY( LAST_DAY( NOW( ) ) ) ) /2;
END IF ;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```